# IOS | Storing blog posts for reading later

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, storage, settings-bundle

I'm rather new to IOS but i managed to get my app to display a list of blog posts from RSS feeds. I would like to give my users the ability to save the blog posts for reading later when they might not have an internet connection.

I will do this through a setting in the settings bundle. I do not however know what the best way is to store blog posts within my app. I am already using core data, would this be a good option for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already using a persistence option then use it for everything, don't mix and match.

If you are already using Core Data then yes it makes sense to keep using it throughout the application for consistency and maintainability.

Comment: Could you point me in the right direction on how would i approach downloading the posts from an RSS feed?

Comment: The posts are already contained in the XML feed.  If they are shortened then it is dependent on the CMS/website and there might not be a way to get the full feed other than grabbing the full HTML for the page.